# how to send account registration confirmation link in mail using php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a project in which I had made web site in php and in that there are one registration form.

there are email field in registration form, now i want to send registration confirmation link in that mail id.

Is there any way for sending confirmation link when user click on submit button using php or java script?

Comment: you want to verify the link also OR just sending a mail ?

Comment: yes ofcause you can send email through `mail()` function.

Comment: yes, I also want to verify the link.. how it will be connect with my project or site?

Comment: right now, my whole project is on localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send email from php if you have SMTP on your server

```
 function sendmail(){

        $subject="bla bla bla";
    $body="Hi boss!!! ";
    $headers='accountrecovery';
    $to="test";
    mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);

    }
```

If you are testing on a local server like wamp or xamp you need to setup SMTP